# "used memory" high, but seems inaccurate - ksysguardd compared to htop?

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring, htop

I'm monitoring a remote machine using `ksysguardd`, and it reports a flat unchanging timeline of 3.6 gigs, with free memory of .20 (the machine has 3.85 gigs available)

Yet with `htop` a range of 400-600 / 3830MB is used.(Which it signifies by a full yellow row of bars.)

As usual I assume its me that is confused.

Am I reading the numbers wrong that ksysguardd says things are running high, or is htop saying things are indeed ok at 600/3830MB used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow bars in htop are for memory used for disk caching, which makes the system run more smoothly. This memory is given to applications whenever they need it, so you're fine!

You can read more on [this](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) (pretty awesome) website.
To know what all of the colours in htop correspond to, read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/180711/what-exactly-do-the-colors-in-htop-status-bars-mean).

Hope that helps!